# AND operator in XPath to check two conditions true

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to write XPath to find id of `<a>` where there will be two `<b>` child nodes having fix value value1 and value2.
If XML is like

```
<a id="1">
  <b>value1</b>
  <b>value2</b>
</a>
```

then this XPath works fine //a[b = 'value1' and b = 'value2']/@id  
      but If XML is like

```
<a id="1">
 <c>somevalue</c>
 <d> <e>somevalue </e> </d>
 <b>value1</b>
 <b>value2</b>
</a>
```

then it return blank record. I want to consider values of `<b>` only.

Comment: Your XPath looks fine. It should work. There may be something going on that you have forgotten to tell us about, for example namespace declarations in an outer element.

Comment: yes correct both <b> elements are inside one element like <f> <b> value1</b> <b> value2 </b> </f>.  I also tried XPath as   //a/f[b = 'value1' and b = 'value2']/@id . It returns blank.

Comment: There is no f element in the source document in your question, and now you introduce one in your comment. We can't help you debug without clear information.